# How to adjust the speed of Objects moving over a 2D playing field?

Tags: java

I'm writing a Tower Defence game and my main component is a grid divided into 40x40 fields (an Object of the Class Field). When the game starts the sortest way to the nearest base is found for every spawn (which is a special kind of field) and saved in its field `int[] path`, which represents a sequence of directions which the monster must follow to reach the base.

I have created a thread that has a loop which moves every monster 1px forward  and increases its field `distance` in each pass. Every time the monster moves I also check if it hasn't stepped on the center of a field. I do it using:

```
if ((monster.getDistance() % FIELD_SIZE /*which is 40*/) == 0)
```

And when it returns 0 the monster changes its direction (reading the position of the next field to reach from its spawn field path).

This works when every enemy moves 1px per pass. But I want them to move with different speed. I found 2 solutions:

1. Move every enemy in a different thread. The higher it's speed is, the shorter would be the Thread.sleep() duration.
2. Move them in loop with different distance.

I prefer the 2. solution but don't know how to implement it. My problem is that most of themonsters would never step on the center of a field and therfore never change direction. If a monster would move with 0.33 speed the distances covered would be: 0.33, 0.66, 0.99 (...) 39.63 (...) 40.13. So it would never reach 40. If i would use ceil, round or floor then it would reach 40 but multiple times what would cause an exception in my app. So my question is how to implement the moving with a float value as the distance and provide that it would reach a multiple of 40 every time but just once per checking?

Comment: AFAIU (which is 'not much') I'd check if the distance is between 39.5 & 40.5 (for instance) and if it does, decide that is the ..limit.

Comment: I need to find a way to provide that no matter what speed enemy has it will always move to 40 value and only once.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the current code.

Comment: I don't know if any code is needed because my problem doesn't correspond to some technical thing. It's more mathematical problem. The shortest I can explain my problem is to find a way that no matter what speed enemy has it's distance will always step on 40-multiple value. So it may move 0.33 but must step on 40, 80, 120 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do collision detection using Pythagorus's theorem

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow((monster.getX() - field.getX()), 2)
 + Math.pow((monster.getY() - field.getY()), 2)) <= field.getRadius()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could feed the new thread the monster and in the run method do what you want with it.

```
public class MoveThread extends Thread{
private Monster myMonster;
public MoveThread(Monster m){
myMonster = m;
}

public void run(){
//do your stuff here
}

}
```