# Should I use Thread Pool instead pool in my situation?

Tags: java, pool

I have simple Tower Defence game. Every monster moves in it's own thread so when new wave comes about 20 new threads are done (from 10 to 25, randomly). I remember something like executor class which is useful in situations when there are many-short lived threads. Like I have. So my questions are:

1. Should I use thread pool and how much would it increase perofrmance?
2. How should I implement it? Should pool be a field?

Comment: Why would every monster move in its own thread, why not just move them all in one function in a run loop?

Comment: You can use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and replace every `new Thread(runnable).start();` with `executorService.submit(runnable);`.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos It's long to explain and not needed in this situation. Shortly - the reason is that every of it moves with different speed.

Comment: Then keep track of speed in a `move()` function instead. Threads will give you loose timing. Trust me when I say it's a terrible idea to do what you're doing as it will run differently on different systems and not give you consistent results.

Comment: I know about it and belive me that if multi thread solution wouldn't be need i wouldn't use it ;) If You're interested - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584259/how-to-adjust-the-speed-of-objects-moving-over-a-2d-playing-field/14584595#14584595

Comment: @MichałTabor It's not needed at all, you can just keep individual move functions that can delay for a certain amount of ticks before moving or move at different rates. I suggest you change the approach to the problem rather than digging yourself into a hole you wont be able to dig yourself out of.

Comment: @JesusRamos Ok I will think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is safe to assume that the interval between waves is more than one second, isn't it? Otherwise, your game would be quite hard to beat. ;-)

I would not expect that using a thread pool will make a difference if you spawn so few threads (15-25 threads are not a big deal). Personally, I would just use `new Thread`. You can always switch to an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) later, but I don't think it is needed in your scenario.

A thread pool is reasonable when you are writing, for example, a web server that has to process several hundred of incoming requests (assuming that each request should be handled in a separate thread). Then a thread pool will likely increase performance but its most important advantage is that it is a handy way to limit resource usage.

Why? If you would just spawn a new thread on each request, you risk that you will soon run out of resources if there are many requests at the same time. Using a thread pool with an upper limit of threads prevents that from happening.

(However, without knowing the details of your application, from a pure design perspective, avoiding threads completely and keeping all the game logic in one thread is definitely something that you should consider. It will make things much simpler. But again, I don't have the details.)

Answer (score 3):

I would have a move() method for each monster and call it periodically.  This way you have just one thread and it should perform just fine.  BTW That one thread can use an ExecutorService if you like.